# Html.CheckboxFor - get selected values by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I want to get selected values in checkbox. However, I am not sure what I must add first.
Do I need to give `id` to `div` and after that, use jQuery? Or do I need to give `name` to `checkbox` and after that use jQuery ?

Also how can I get selected values by using javascript ?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Name)

    <div>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.Checked)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => item.Checked, item.Name)
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `CheckBoxFor()`, you need to add HTML properties.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.Checked, new { id = "checked-@Model.IndexOf(item)" })
```

Of course, that assumes your Model derives from `List()`, or `IList()`.

However, both of those are bad ideas, because it can cause issues with your serialization. Your `Model` should only ever be an object. If you want to pass a collection, have that be a property on your model object.

Check out [my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167227/single-property-not-getting-bound-on-httppost) which explains why this is a bad idea.